# Why is fadeIn flickering when loading?

Tags: php, jquery, menu, fadein, flicker

I've made a site from an youtube tutorial. [Here's my test site](http://superfresh.se/laddasidan/). And
[here's the tutorial (final step of 3)](http://youtu.be/H0XnZsxxKFQ) if it helps. No CSS used yet.

When I click a link in the menu. Everything fades like supposed. But at the end of fade animation the previous page flickers.

**Me**
I'm totally new to JavaScript.

*index.php:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>SuperFresh</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<a class="menu_top" href="pages/home.php">Home</a> /
<a class="menu_top" href="pages/portfolio.php">Portfolio</a> /
<a class="menu_top" href="pages/contact.php">Contact</a> /

<div id="content_area"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/nav.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

*nav.js:*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#content_area').load($('.menu_top:first').attr('href'));
});

$('.menu_top').click(function () {
    var href=$(this).attr('href');
    $('#content_area').hide('slow').load(href).fadeIn('slow');

    return false;
});
```

Comment: You are right. But I could not get the index.php to work. =/ So I submittet my test site ...

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
var href=$(this).attr('href');    
$('#content_area').hide('slow').load(href).fadeIn('slow');
```

With:

```
$('#content_area').hide('slow', function(){
    $(this).load($(this).attr('href')).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

This will fade it out and wait until the animation is complete before calling that function and loading in the new content.

Check out [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) for more info.

Comment: No flickering but the href's just show home.php dispite of what link I am clicking. Have a look at [test site](http://superfresh.se/laddasidan_stackflow02/).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$('.menu_top').click(function () {
    var href=$(this).attr('href');
    var page = $('<div/>').attr('id','page').load(href);
    $('#content_area').fadeOut('slow').html('').html(page).fadeIn('slow');

    return false;
});
```

Comment: [Here it is with your code](http://superfresh.se/laddasidan_stackflow01/) Jai. It fades in twice now. But that's less irritating than before. Do you perhaps know why it's does the fadein twice?

Comment: I'v updated [the test site](http://superfresh.se/laddasidan_stackflow01/) with your update. But there's still double fadein. You are way batter than me so I can't see what your update do.

Answer (score 0):

you can  use handlers with your own functions...

for ex :

```
$('#show').click(function() {
    $('#myDiv').show(0, onDivShow);
});

$('#hide').click(function() {
    $('#myDiv').hide(0, onDivHide);
});


function onDivShow() { alert('is shown'); }
function onDivHide() { alert('is hidden'); }
```

Comment: I know so little about javascrip so I can't implement your code. Too bad, it looks solid.